# jquery-ui autocomplete displaying behind side nav

Tags: jquery, css

Basically what the title says. My search dropdown in jquery-ui autocomplete displaying behind the navbar.

Steps to recreate the bug:
1) Hit the plus button
2) Type in "A" into the search bar

Heres a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m5oydqkr/1/

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <form role="search">
        <input class="searchbar" id="search" type="text" list="games" placeholder="Search games...">
    </form>
    <hr>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-darkslategrey">
    <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'home' %}">WTF</a>
    <div class="d-flex order-lg-1 ml-auto pr-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
          <li class="nav-item text-light">
            <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><i class="far fa-plus-square fa-lg"></i></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

</script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        let availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
        ];
    https://jsfiddle.net/m5oydqkr/#
        $("#search").autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,
          focus: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
          },
          select: function(event, ui) {

            window.location.href = ui.item.value;

            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
          },
          minLength: 1,
        });
      });

</script>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kanhasahu/oqrtpaLv/

Only adding in css z-index only will findout you autocomplete result, result added css will help to get additional effect.

> .ui-autocomplete{
>       z-index: 9;
>     }

```
ul.ui-autocomplete{
  list-style:none inside;
}
.ui-autocomplete{
    position: relative;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:3px 8px;
    border-top:1px solid #333333;
    background:#666666;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Message showing in behind because you are not give any class and position to the message div, kindly assign class to the message div and because the side nave bar position is fixed and z-index is higher so your can add any class and apply my suggests css to resolve the problem.

The color combination is as per me, you an change as per your need.

```
Suggested css

.search-result-text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    color: #f00;
    background: #000
}
```